# Cannot find module in .mjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-lib.js

I am new at javascript and i have a problem with turkish characters. I use node.js

I have followed this steps:

git clone https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake.git 
cd pdfmake
npm install
npm run build

my pdfmake location is: C:\Users\islah\WebstormProjects\js-projects2\ttf\pdfmake   
my .mjs file location is : C:\Users\islah\WebstormProjects\js-projects2\firstdeneme.mjs

```
import { PDFDocument, rgb } from 'pdf-lib';
import pdfMake from './ttf/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';
import pdfFonts from './ttf/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.mjs';
import fs from 'fs';

pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

const customFont = {
    Roboto: {
        normal: 'fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
        bold: 'fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf',
        italics: 'fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf'
    }
};

pdfMake.fonts = customFont;// Register the font with pdfmake
```

It gives me a error like this

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\islah\WebstormProjects\js-projects2\ttf\pdfmake\build\vfs_fonts.mjs' imported from C:\Users\islah\WebstormProjects\js-projects2\firstdeneme.mjs
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:326:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

if i dont use the .mjs .js extension in import part i give also error like cannot find module

also i have a problem like Assigned expression type {Roboto: {normal: string, italics: string, bold: string, bolditalics: string}} is not assignable to type FontFaceSet
\ how can i fix this thanks.